# /dev/tcp not present in Linux

Tags: linux, c, tcp

I am porting C/pro*c code from UNIX to Linux. The code is:

```c
#define __NFDBIT       (8 * sizeof(unsigned long))
#define __FD_SETSIZ    1024
#define __FDSET_LONG   (__FD_SETSIZ/__NFDBIT)
typedef struct {
    unsigned long fds_bits [__FDSET_LONG];
} __ernel_fd_set;

typedef __ernel_fd_set           fd_set_1;
int main()
{
    fd_set_1 listen_set;
    int listen_sd;
    int socket_id;
    FD_ZERO(&listen_set);
    socket_id = t_open("/dev/tcp", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK, (struct t_info *) 0);
    if ( socket_id <0 )
    {
        exit(FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In UNIX the value of socket_id is `> 0` in Linux it is `-1`. Reason is in UNIX, there is a `/dev/tcp`. This is not present on Linux. Also in UNIX this `tcp` file is character special file which is different from normal file.

Is there any way to create same character special file in Linux as in UNIX or how to proceed this further?

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use [Berkeley sockets/POSIX sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)?

Comment: yes Jofel. In that case I need to modify large amount of existing code which is not feasible. I'am looking for replacement of /dev/tcp in Linux or how it should be created in Linux to make it work as in Unix. Following are information about /dev/tcp in Unix.

Comment: How do you compile your software? AFAIK on Linux, XTI/TLI is only supported by some extra libraries like [Linux Fast Stream from OpenSS7](http://www.openss7.org/streams_pkg.html) or emulators like [iBCS](http://www.jaggycraft.co.uk/linux/ibcs/). There is no way to simply create /dev/tcp on Linux. You may find /dev/tcp used from bash, but in this case it is just a relict which tells bash to open a tcp socket. The device does not really exists.

Comment: cc tet.o  -o test-L$ORACLE_HOME/lib64 -lxnet  executed binary file test                               There is a way to create character file tcp under /dev using command mknod tcp c <x> <y> .  In unix the device entries for tcp are 42,2.  that is file command (file /dev/tcp) shows "character special (42/2)" where x = 42 and y =2.  But with same entries I created in Linux as mknod tcp c 42 2.again socket_id is -1.  Here the problem is device entries to be used Linux.

Comment: @smilebhuff It is not enough to create the node, someone in the kernel must be responsible for it - which is not the case under Linux.

Comment: Your code has terrible portability problems.   Even disregarding the problem you already have with `/dev/tcp` you are using file descriptor sets incorrectly.   I fear that `/dev/tcp` may just be the most obvious of a sequence of problems with your code.    You also seem to have some forbidden naming conventions too (you're using identifiers in your application programming which are reserved for use by the C implementation).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`t_open()` and its associated `/dev/tcp` and such are part of the [TLI/XTI interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_Transport_Interface), which lost the battle for TCP/IP APIs to BSD sockets.

On Linux, there is a `/dev/tcp` of sorts. It isn't a real file or kernel device. It's something [specially provided by Bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), and it exists only for redirections. This means that even if one were to create an in-kernel `/dev/tcp` facility, it would be masked in interactive use 99%[*] of the time by the shell.

The best solution really is to switch to BSD sockets. Sorry.

You might be able to get the [strxnet](http://www.openss7.org/strxnet_pkg.html) XTI emulation layer to work, but you're better off putting your time into getting off XTI. It's a dead API, unsupported not just on Linux, but also on the BSDs, including OS X.

(By the way, the strxnet library won't even build on the BSDs, because it depends on [LiS](http://www.gcom.com/home/linux/lis/index.html), a component of the Linux kernel. It won't even `configure` on a stock BSD or OS X system, apparently because it also depends on GNU sed.)

[*] I base this wild guess on the fact that Bash is the default shell for non-root users in all Linux distros I've used. You therefore have to go out of your way on Linux, as a rule, to get something other than Bash.

Comment: Warren thanks for your inputs.  Sorry I'am very new to these socket programming and API concepts.  Please bare with my questions.  What do you mean by " strxnet XTI emulation latyer"  we recently installed one of the packages of strxnet (strxnet-0.9.2.10.tar) to get some of openss7 libraries/headerfiles.What can I do more with that?

Comment: I've never used it myself, but from a quick examination of the tarball, it looks like once it's installed, it provides an XTI emulation layer. You should just be able to point your compiler at it with `-I` and `-L` flags and expect it to work. But if it does not, I wouldn't throw a lot of time at it.

Comment: I know about -I and -L which is to include headers/libraries respectively.  But what exactly I have to do here with -I / -L? sorry again if  my question is wrong.

Comment: That depends on where the package installed the files. Find the library file, `libstrxnet.so.*`: that directory is what you pass to `-L`. Find `xti.h`: pass that directory to `-I`. You will also need `-lstrxnet` at minimum. Bottom line: see the strxnet docs.

Comment: Warren, that is what I have done during compilation.  please see the steps I gave in previous command.  This library has t_open() function.  But problem is not with this function.  Problem is with /dev/tcp which t_open is trying to open.

Comment: cc tet.o -o test-L$ORACLE_HOME/lib64 -lxnet this is how compiled my code to get binary executable test.

Comment: If you're getting `libxnet` as part of Pro*C — don't guess, go look — then that is sufficient and the problem is probably that you haven't enabled the STREAMS option in your Linux kernel. If `libxnet*` isn't in that `$ORACLE_HOME/lib64` directory, you need to build and install it. You would need *separate* `-L` and `-I` flags for it in that case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3450/discussion-between-warren-young-and-smileybhuff)