# Can pure bash perform a port scan?

Tags: bash, networking

Without using any external programs, using solely the bash language, is it possible to perform a port scan on a remote host?

After looking through bash's builtins, I would say: no. But maybe there are workarounds or additional possible commands it's possible to carry out which aren't in the bash builtins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Bash’s TCP connection support to check for open ports:

```
if 2>/dev/null >"/dev/tcp/${IP}/${PORT}"; then echo open; fi
```

will check whether a connection can be opened to port `${PORT}` on `${IP}`.

The test itself is performed by attempting the redirection to `/dev/tcp/${IP}/${PORT}`; redirecting standard error to `/dev/null` (`2>/dev/null`) hides the resuling error message when the target port isn’t reachable.

This can be used in a loop to scan all ports.

Comment: I've never heard of bash's "built-in /dev/tcp device file" before. This is also the first time I am seeing this `[n]<>word` redirection operator. Guess I've got a lot of exploration and discovery to look forward to, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @theonlygusti in this case, the operator doesn't matter: /dev/tcp/host/port work the same with >, <, <> or >>. The file descriptor will be in read-write mode in any case.

Comment: and that could be done simpler without any exec, with `if 2>/dev/null >"/dev/tcp/$IP/$PORT"; then echo open; fi`

Comment: I have an Ubuntu 19.10 and inside **/dev/** i dont have tcp. Its this normal? does the solution provided is specific to an OS release?

Comment: @BANJOSA Bash handles `/dev/tcp` itself, there is no corresponding directory in `/dev`. See also [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/305811/86440) and the links there.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt thanks for the information, now makes sense to me :)